# can't dispatch an action inside useEffect react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

i have a problem when dispatching an action inside useEffect in functional component

in class component it is looks like this

```
import getAllItem from './actions/item'

export class Home extends Component {

  state = {   menus: []  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getAllItem())
    this.setState({ menus: this.props.menu })
   })
  }

...
...

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { menu: state.reItem.itemList}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

in console it's return an array of my menus

i want convert it into functional component ,and i've tried

```
import getAllItem from './actions/item'

export default function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const menuState = useSelector(state => state.reItem.itemList)
  const [menus, setMenus] = useState();

   useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(getAllItem())
     setMenus(menuState);
   }, [])
...
...
```

i expected my functional component have the same result as class component do ,but in console it returning
"TypeError:(0,_item.default)is not a function"

my action code is simple

```
export const getAllItem = () => {
    return {
        type: 'GET_ITEM',
        payload: Axios.get(`${URL}/item/`)
    }
}
```

and the reducer

```
const initialState = {
    itemList: []
}

const item = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_ITEM':
            return {
                ...state,
                itemList: action.payload.data.result
            }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `then` from `useEffect` but not from `componentDidMount` did you change your action creator to return a promise?

Comment: @Dupocas i forgot to edit ,i've tried then in both component too but the functional component still have same result

Comment: You set the action payload to a promise: `payload: Axios.get(`${URL}/item/`)` maybe you should have a look at redux thunk.

Comment: You have to `@` if you want to reply to someone. Yes there is a big problem with your action, that's not how redux works, you are assigning a promise to action.payload and in the reducer this promise magically changed to the resolved promise value.

Comment: @Dupocas thanks bro your answer was helpful ,and i forgot to put action inside curly bracket ,@HMR thank for the information ,i have to learn more about redux

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck

Comment: Good luck, I think you almost there but need something like [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to do asynchronous stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing named exports incorrectly.

your code:`import getAllItem from './actions/item'`

correct import:`import {getAllItem} from './actions/item'`